# Shorten SQL update query

Tags: sql

Is there a way to shorten this update query? I'm new to this and not sure how can I further shorten it

```
UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET [WW0] = 0
WHERE [WW0] IS NULL

UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET [WW0+1] = 0
WHERE [WW0+1] IS NULL

UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET [WW0+2] = 0
WHERE [WW0+2] IS NULL

UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET [WW0+3] = 0
WHERE [WW0+3] IS NULL

UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET [WW0+4] = 0
WHERE [WW0+4] IS NULL

UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET [WW0+5] = 0
WHERE [WW0+5] IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the type of database - looks like SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what RDMBS you're using, but your posted SQL looks like T-SQL (for Microsoft SQL Server or Sybase), in that case then this single `UPDATE` statement should do the trick:

```sql
UPDATE
    [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET
    [WW0]   = CASE WHEN [WW0]   IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [WW0]   END,
    [WW0+1] = CASE WHEN [WW0+1] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [WW0+1] END,
    [WW0+2] = CASE WHEN [WW0+2] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [WW0+2] END,
    [WW0+3] = CASE WHEN [WW0+3] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [WW0+3] END,
    [WW0+4] = CASE WHEN [WW0+4] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [WW0+4] END,
    [WW0+5] = CASE WHEN [WW0+5] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE [WW0+5] END
WHERE
    [WW0]   IS NULL OR
    [WW0+1] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+2] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+3] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+4] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+5] IS NULL
```

Or with `COALESCE` (or `ISNULL` if you're feeling brave):

```sql
UPDATE
    [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET
    [WW0]   = COALESCE( [WW0]  , 0 ),
    [WW0+1] = COALESCE( [WW0+1], 0 ),
    [WW0+2] = COALESCE( [WW0+2], 0 ),
    [WW0+3] = COALESCE( [WW0+3], 0 ),
    [WW0+4] = COALESCE( [WW0+4], 0 ),
    [WW0+5] = COALESCE( [WW0+5], 0 )
WHERE
    [WW0]   IS NULL OR
    [WW0+1] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+2] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+3] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+4] IS NULL OR
    [WW0+5] IS NULL
```

Comment: Yep. PL/SQL is Oracle's programming language that they built into their DBMS, though. You probably just mean SQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No, I meant Oracle PL/SQL: I wrote my answer when the OP's question post was tagged with PL/SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70779384/1

Comment: @Dai: PL/SQL is only used to write stored procedures, functions or triggers. An UPDATE statement is just SQL

Comment: you are missing an `END` for all your CASE expressions. They can also be simplified by using `coalesce()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 

Answer (score 0):

One update for all.

```
UPDATE [Tbl_SS_Utilization(F03)_Copy1]
SET 
  [WW0]     = COALESCE([WW0], 0)
, [WW0+1]   = COALESCE([WW0+1], 0)
, [WW0+2]   = COALESCE([WW0+2], 0)
, [WW0+3]   = COALESCE([WW0+3], 0)
, [WW0+4]   = COALESCE([WW0+4], 0)
, [WW0+5]   = COALESCE([WW0+5], 0)
WHERE ([WW0] & [WW0+1] & [WW0+2] & [WW0+3] & [WW0+4] & [WW0+5]) IS NULL;
```

[test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fa21e0708ea2cdb6be333ab0cb34f8cd)